# Adding class to ValidationSummary

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Apparently the `unobtrusive js` and `ModelState` errors do not play together. What I want to accomplish is 2 things. When either a `ModelState` or a client side error occurs, it will be displayed by the validation-summary-errors class.

The problem I am having is that instead of using the helper,

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;"></ul>
</div>
```

It will not display `ModelState` errors thus I tried with following code,

**Code :**

```
if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
   <div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
       <ul style="list-style-type:none;"></ul>
   </div>
}
else
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

But then I can't format the output because of the helper (like also removing the bullet from the list)!

**Here is the javascript :**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('form').each(function () {
         var theForm = $(this);
         theForm.submit(function () {
             if ($(this).valid()) {
                 if ($(this).find('.validation-summary-valid').length) {
                     $('.validation-summary-errors').hide();
                 }
             } else {
                 if ($(this).find('.validation-summary-errors').length) {
                     $('.validation-summary-errors')
                         .addClass('alert alert-danger');
                 }
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: All you need is `@Html.ValidationSummary()` and remove your script (suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand the basics of validation - the first sentence in your question is wrong)

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "validation-summary-errors" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unobtrusive and model state do play well together.

You have hard-coded your view to show an empty list when the validation fails and only use the Razor helper when the validation is successful, so it will always show an empty list.

Just use `@Html.ValidationSummary()` without the `if` block.  It will automatically be empty if the model is valid.

If no model validation messages are being displayed when you expect them to be, set a breakpoint in your controller on `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and inspect the model.  Then check your data annotations.  For debugging purposes, you can manually add a model state error `ModelSatate.AddModelError("fieldname", "This field has an error");` just to prove the Razor helper is working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inputs.
I ended up removing the if statement for the ValidationSummary(). To handle both what I ended up doing was, add a second little script similar to the shown above but for the window.onload event. This way it catches the ModelState errors while the one above handles the obtrusive.